# Cannot access column name in pgfplotsstable

Tags: floats, pgfplotstable

I followed the standard way (to the extent of my knowledge) of accessing the column name in pgfplotstable but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column name=$\epsilon$, column type={|c|}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=$\phi$, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{test.csv}
\caption{Results}
\end{figure}
```

and this is what it generates:
[image]

It is supposed to have `\phi` and `\epsilon` in there but it doesn't. This is what the data file test.csv contains

```
parameter,test
1,2
1,2
1,3
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your column names are not `name` and `surname` but `parameter`  and `test`. Where do you want `\phi` and `\epsilon`?

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar , I need to replace parameter and test with \phi and \epsilon respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the proper header names of columns. Your columns have names `parameter` and `test` but you are using `name` and `surname`. Change them to

```
    columns/parameter/.style={column name=$\epsilon$, column type={|c|}},
    columns/test/.style={column name=$\phi$, column type={|c|}},
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
  parameter,test
    1,2
    1,2
    1,3
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[H]        %% why figure?
  \centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/parameter/.style={column name=$\epsilon$, column type={|c|}},
    columns/test/.style={column name=$\phi$, column type={c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{test.csv}
\caption{Results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also corrected the second `column type={c|}` (for test).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you happen to know to center the caption below the table? also, I only get a "." after Figure1 instead of ":". So I am getting "Figure1." instead of "Figure1:", do you happen to know why? anyways thank you.

Comment: @kolonel: I am not getting both of them. Hence it is hard to say without seeing your code. Have you put `\centering` as I did? `Figure 1:` is default. May you have changed something, may be with `caption` package?

Comment: actually its okay. Thanks a lot for your help